# How does malloc know how much memory space is treated for an index?

Tags: c, malloc

When we use `malloc`, it returns a pointer to the beginning of a fixed sized memory address that was passed to malloc. For example, `malloc(40)` will throw me some uninitialized piece of memory that is 40 bytes long. The thing is, I have seen examples of code where people index into this piece of memory. My question is, how does `malloc` define the size of an index?

For example, take this piece of code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{   
    char **array;
    array = malloc(3 * sizeof(char *));

    for (int i=0; i < 3; i++) {
        array[i] = malloc(10);
    }
    
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        free(array[i]);
    }
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

I would first like to explain what I believe is happening and would hope someone could correct me about any incorrect ideas that I have.

`char **array` creates the variable "array", where it will become a pointer, to a character pointer. This means if we dereference this value, it will give us a memory address location of where the `char` is stored.

`array = malloc(3 * sizeof(char *))` . Let's assume here that `sizeof(char *)` will always return 8. Carrying on, this will create an uninitialized piece of memory that is 32 bytes long. They key point here is that it is 32 bytes long, how does it treat an indexable size?

`array[i] = malloc(10)` is the part of my confusion here. We have an uninitialized piece of memory that is 32 bytes long, how do we index into it?

I have an idea which I would like to draw out and hope someone could correct any misunderstanding I have.

```
      0x02                     0x0A                 0x12
[     0x90             |       0x91           |     0x92           ]
 <-- sizeof(char*)  ->  <-- sizeof(char*)  ->  <-- sizeof(char*)  ->
       ^
       |  
       |
    0x01 (memory address of variable array) (array - points to 0x02)

-- Random memory locations

0x90 -- | Starting from the memory address location 0x90, the next sizeof(char) bytes will representing the value in this memory address location.
['c']

0x91
['a']

0x92
['t']
```

From my understanding malloc will know the indexable size from the cast we have done on our initial pointer, i.e. the `char*` inside of `char** array`. This means, that our pointer that was returned from `malloc(40)` will pointer to, in this example, a memory address space located at `0x02` (The beginning of the array).

Each time we perform the action `array[i]` we are actually doing `0x02 + sizeof(char*) * i` which will push the pointer to the beginning of a new location. This means for example when we do `array[1]` we are actually doing `0x02 + sizeof(char*) * 1` which would push us to `0x02 + 8 (0x0A)`. This means that from the memory address location `0x0A` the next `sizeof(char *)` bytes will be read as the **index** stored in this place in memory. In this example it would be a `char *`, in my example I have written `0x90`, meaning some other place in memory `0x90` the next `sizeof(char)`, i.e. 1 byte will have the actual value. The actual value representing 'c' (for example), but this could be located somewhere else in memory, not related to malloc.

Using this formula we can have for example an integer array returned from malloc, by having `int* ten_int_array = malloc(10 *sizeof(10))`. Now the formula would be adjusted to `ten_int_array + sizeof(int) * i`. Which would make malloc not a fixed size indexable.

Thank you for any replies, I am trying to verify my assumptions here.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `malloc`. It is not `malloc` that is doing the indexing. It is the compiler. When the code does indexing the compiler will generate the right offsets based on the type of the pointer. All `malloc` does is allocate the size of memory that you tell it to (well possibly a bit more for book keeping and alignment). So it's not entirely clear what your question is.

Comment: when you have a `T *` and you index from that, you access memory locations as if it contained an array of contiguous elements of `T`.

Comment: The size of the pointer is not important.  The pointer is just a memory address.  What is important is what the compiler does when it calculates an offset into the array.  It does this by multiplying the array index by the array's element size.  The resulting number is the offset (in bytes) from the memory address stored in the pointer to the indexed element in the array.

Comment: All malloc does is allocate a block of memory of the size you requested, and then return a memory address to the first byte of that block.

Comment: Reading these comments, if I were to space this out in a formula it would be something such as, `T* example = malloc(10 * sizeof(T))`, then `T[i]` would therefore actually be, `example + sizeof(T) * i`.

Comment: I have tested this manually and the answer seems to be `example + i` indexes correctly, however I feel like this should not be the case. Is there hidden compiler magic automatically off setting it by the type times five? Surely it would not be the memory address location plus actual five.

Comment: "*Is there hidden compiler magic*". It is actually part of the C language. Called "pointer arithmetic". Do a search for that term and read all about it.

Comment: "Is there hidden compiler magic" - no, otherwise how should indexing happen? `char *c` vs `int *i`, `c + 1` should increase the address by `sizeof(char)` and `i + 1` should increase the address by `sizeof(int)`. A pointer to a **type** tells the compiler by how many bytes - `sizeof(T)` - it has to move to the right (or left) if doing pointer arithmetic. And if you have a pointer to a pointer (to a type) then doing arithmetic on the pointer moves it by `sizeof(pointer)` and not `sizeof(type)`.

Comment: Btw. `*(pointer + n)` is equivalent to `pointer[n]`, if not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what happening. Supposedly that you are running it on a 64-bit system where memory address needs 8 bytes (64 bits).

`char *str;` declares a pointer variable denoted by `*` which can point to a place in memory. By the above convention it is supposed to be 8 bytes large. The compiler knows that the object it is supposed to point to is a `char`.  It has absolutely no idea if there should be other chars which follow or precedes this location, only the programmer does.

So, `str = malloc(10);` allocates enough memory space to keep 10 characters, including terminating '0'. The address of the memory is assigned to the pointer variable `str`.

`char **array;` declares a pointer `*` to a pointer `*`. This yet another 8-byte variable which, as the compiler knows, points to another pointer which itself points to a char. Similarly to the previous, it has no idea if there are more pointers adjacent to the one it is supposed to point.

`array = malloc(3 * sizeof(char*));` allocates enough space in memory to keep exactly 3 pointers to char. The result of allocation will be assigned to `array`.

In ‘c’ operator `[]` applied to a pointer is similar to the one applied to an array variable. So `array[1]` returns a pointer #2 from the memory allocated above.

`array[i] = malloc(10);` allocates memory for a string of 10 characters and assigns the result to the pointer which s pointed by the array[i]. `free(array[i])` frees this memory.

As a result, you have a two-level dynamic structure.

```
           |-malloc(3 * sizeof (char*)) == 24 bytes
           |
           V
array --> [0] --> malloc(10) == 10 bytes
          [1] --> malloc(10)
          [2] --> malloc(10)
```

So, when you free, you need to `free(array[i]) //0..2` first then  `free(array)` because after freeing array, the memory it points too becomes invalidated and you cannot use it.